# 'Bounty Expires Soon' notification doesn't correctly render apostrophes

Tags: bug, notifications, active-bounties

The 'Bounty Expiring Soon' notification does not render apostrophes correctly, yet the 'Bounty Expires in one day' notification does:

[image: Notifications]